# Change display timezone in Google Cloud Platform logs

Tags: logging, timezone, google-cloud-platform

How do I change the timezone for the displayed times in Google Cloud Platform logs?  It is currently showing the logs with CEST time, and I would like to see UTC time (which is what the sever it is logging always uses).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Update:** This answer is now obsolete, as Google changed the UI. See nilpunning's answer below.

Old answer:

It **is** possible to set the time zone, but the feature is almost un-discoverable.

When viewing your logs,

1. Open the time range selector menu (the menu which says “Last hour” or similar)
2. Choose “Jump to time”
3. In the time picker that appears, choose your time zone and click “Go” (don't worry about the actual time that you're going to)

Your logging display time zone is now set.

Comment: If you are in the "new" logs viewer, you will have to go back to the Legacy Logs Viewer by clicking the OPTIONS button. Follow the instructions above, and then return to the new viewer after you've changed the timezone. The new viewer will retain the timezone you set.

Answer (score 16):

**Google recently updated the legacy logging to a new style**

[image]

**I have been looking for this for a very long, hope this would help.**

Answer (score 5):

In the "New" Logs Explorer, in the Query Results card there are columns: SEVERITY, TIMESTAMP, and SUMMARY.  The TIMESTAMP column header has a drop down which allows you to change the timezone.

Comment: This answer is more up to date than the currently-accepted answer which requires the user to revert to a legacy version of the Logs Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support in Stackdriver (the tool used for viewing Google Cloud Platform logs) for directly changing the time zone used for displaying logs. From what I can tell, the time zone displayed is the time zone configured on your Google account.

Having said that, Stackdriver does offer advanced filtering mechanism for filtering logs. One of the criteria you can use for filtering is `timestamp` and you can configure time zones in this filter.

You can follow these steps:

1. Open `Menu -> Logging -> Logs`. This will open the `Stackdriver Logging` page.
2. You will see a text box which says `Filter by label or text search`. This is the simple filter mode.
3. You need to switch to advanced filter mode by clicking the down arrow on the right of the text box and selecting `Convert to advanced filter`.
4. In the textbox you can enter the advanced filter query. For example you can enter `timestamp >= "2017-06-05T21:10:00-07:00"` to filter and display only logs whose timestamp is at or after `2017-06-05 9:10 PM PDT`
5. If you do not want to specify any time zone offset and just filter based on UTC time, you can use this format `2017-06-05T21:10:00Z`.

The format of the Log entry and the fields like timestamp are documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs#the_logentry_type).

> **timestamp**
>
> string
>
> The time the event occurred: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ".

Some more pointers about searching by time is available [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_viewer_v2?hl=en_US&_ga=1.162061500.1655476696.1496939695#searching_by_time).

You can also combine timestamp with other search criteria, specify both `>=` and `<=` to specify a timestamp range, etc. to narrow down your results.

Further reading about using Advanced Log filters [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced_filters).